# IOT device getting a double post from Axios

Tags: lua, axios

I have an IOT device, its coded in Lua, I didn't do that part of the project, so I don't know much about it.

I have 2 almost identical axios posts.

1. run via an app

```
await axios.post(url,{ cmd:'{"cmd": {"uuid":"'+serial+'","name":"RR","value":"'+key+'"}}' } , { auth: { username: 'admin', password: 'rLVeGRk9ezWj' } }
```

2. run via a local HTML page to test:

```
const body = { cmd:'{"cmd": {"uuid":"'+serial+'","name":"RR","value":"'+key+'"}}' }

const resp2 = await axios.post(url, body, { auth: { username: 'admin', password: 'rLVeGRk9ezWj' })
```

In the lua side, the HTML example works perfectly. My app version (#1 above), actually sends twice. Causes a "Ignoring new incoming data. Failed to get header".

I compared headers, content-length and looks identical.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, hard a hard time getting it on right line... small update... I did some more tests, and it seems the issue is safari/IOS. When I tested in Android it works. So, I need to refocus my research on safari/IOS

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else experiencing this, the Lua device was splitting the data when it was too long. The IOT developer had to make a change to handle long posts